# Accessing/decoding JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

Rephrasing this question.

1. User clicks on a link which takes them to **editUser.php?id=1** (where ID is the users ID number)
2. The editUser.php page on document ready calls the function `loadAjaxVals(script, json_action, id);`. This function is located in an external JS library. The script and json_action values aren't relevant to this question. The ID is the ID from the URL query string
3. The loadAjaxVals() sends a request to a PHP script which returns the data to loadAjaxVals(script, json_action, id) as json_encoded() data
4. loadAjaxVals() takes the json encoded data and loops through it outputting the results to a form on editUser.php. The script takes the name value pairs from the JSON encoded data which become form element IDs and values
5. The form is populated and were all done.

However I want a second script located on editUser.php to parse the JSON and extract 1 piece of data from it.

I dont know how to access the JSON or parse the JSON.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. have a look at my test: http://jsfiddle.net/vHp8j/

Comment: Ummm, what's the issue here?  If I do `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"enable_class":"disable"}');`, then `obj.enable_class === "enable"` is obviously `false`.

Comment: Why are you calling a function on `$.fn` directly?  That's not how that's supposed to work.  Functions attached to `$.fn` are jQuery plugins, and you're supposed to call them on a jQuery object, like `$('#myEle').loadAjaxVals()`.  If your function doesn't act on a jQuery object, don't put it in `$.fn`.

Comment: @AbdelOlakara updating the post above

Comment: @Rocket updated my code, thanks. In regards to what the issue is, the page is populated from an external script, but the JSON string is also returned to the page that made the call. If I took the script from the script library, placed it onto the page that is making the call I could access the JSON string without any issue as it would be within the function. Also..unsure as to whether parseJson requires the entire string, or a fragment of the string.

Comment: @MarkLawrence: I'm still not sure what your issue is.  Oh and yea, `$.parseJSON` requires the *entire* JSON string, not just part of it.

Comment: `var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON);  console.log(obj.results.user_guest === 'guest');`.

Comment: @AbdelOlakara Correct me if Im wrong here...your fiddle resolves correctly as the string has already been placed in parseJson(). How do I get the JSON string into parseJson() from the browser, if I dont know the contents of the string? Does that make sense?

Comment: @Rocket Great, thanks. Thats the issue, Im not using the entire string. However the string is dynamic, its contents will be different each call. So I guess I need to work out how to get an unknown JOSN string to be parsed...

Comment: @MarkLawrence: Of course it's going to be different each call, though I assume its keys will be the same (I assume it'll always have a `user_guest` field).

Comment: @MarkLawrence: `if I dont know the contents of the string`.  What are you talking about?  You can't parse something if you don't have it.  Wait.  You do have this JSON in a javaScript variable, right?

Comment: @Rocket Im going to answer no to that. I need to get the JSON into the script

Comment: @MarkLawrence: Where is the JSON on the page?  How is it returned?  What exactly does `$.fn.loadAjaxVals` do?

Comment: @MarkLawrence.. you are getting your JSON through ajax right? So, you have a general form and you know what keys your JSON will hold for sure, right? When what is the issue in getting the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is only available in the `loadAjaxVals` function.  I suggest you edit the `loadAjaxVals` to accept a callback function.

Something like this:

```
function loadAjaxVals(script, json_action, id, callback){
    // get JSON
    // code
    // parse JSON
    // more code
    if($.isFunction(callback)){
        callback(data); // pass callback the parsed JSON data
    }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
loadAjaxVals(script, json_action, id, function(data){
    // use data
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the 'in' operator to check if an object has an attribute ...

```
alert('enable_class' in obj)
```

should be true if indeed that object hast enbable_class either wise false

As for your second question, it may be possible that are you are using a cache version of the object, this is quite common, trust me, what I would recommend is clearing your cache and trying again, I also recommend Google Chrome javascript debugger which is built in and comes along with a very nice console and host of other niceties ... :)

If indeed the problem is the cache their are a couple ways around it ... I'll elaborate once you've confirmed it.